# Simplification of double symbolic sums containing a DiscreteDelta without explicit summation range

Tags: programming, simplifying-expressions, symbolic

I am trying to get Mathematica to automatically do simplifications like the following:

$$\sum\limits_{q}^{q\in qV}\sum\limits_{q'}^{q'\in q'V}{f(q)g(q')\delta(q-q')}=\sum_{q}^{q\in qV}{f(q)g(q)}.$$

Where the range of values that $q$ and $q'$ are denoted by $qV$ and $q'V$ respectively and are the same. With pen an paper it is really easy to do that kind of simplifications because I know that both variables $q$ and $q'$ have the same range and that the Discrete Delta function $\delta(q-q')$ kills one of the sums.

I have solved it, but it seems to me that I haven't done it in the most elegant/efficient way. My solution is:

```
Clear[qV, qpV, f,g, MyDiscreteDelta]
a = Sum[f[q] Sum[g[qp] MyDiscreteDelta[q, qp], {qp, qpV}], {q, qV}]
b = % /. {qpV -> {q, q1, q2, q3, q4}}
c = % /. {MyDiscreteDelta[x_, y_] -> HoldForm[If[x =!= y, 0, 1]]}
d = ReleaseHold[%]
```

$a$ defines the sum and I deliberately leave the sum range undefined as even though I know the real range of number I will be summing, it's too large to be put directly and more importantly, at this stage of the calculation I don't care about it, I am just interested in simplifying the result as much as possible, i.e., get rid of one of the sums by using the delta function. I am not using Mathematica defined function DiscreteDelta because a) it takes too long and b) when used symbolically it is left unevaluated.

First thing I need to do to get rid of one of the sums is to give it a range to sum through, in doing so, I am actually giving it a list of possible variables that it could take(assuming that in the general case I will be having more than two summations and I will have more than one delta function in many of the variables). That's done in $b$.

$c$ changes the empty definition of MyDiscreteDelta but I need to hold it as if I don't do so, it will all be evaluated to $0$. The last step, $d$ evaluates the expression and gives the results I want.

This works, but I was wondering if there is a simpler way of doing it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not using the built-in `KroneckerDelta` ?

Comment: I did a test, changing `code` MyDiscreetDelta[q,qp] `code` to `code` KroneckerDelta[q,qp] `code` in (a) and only evaluating (a) and (b). It is very slow.

It does simplify to 1 when q==qp but on the other cases, it is just left unevaluated, the same as DiscreteDelta. I can individually reproduce the expected behaviour if I write `code` Assuming[q != qp, Simplify[KroneckerDelta[q, qp]]] `code` or `code` Assuming[q != qp, Simplify[DiscreteDelta[q, qp]]] `code`. But it doesn't work if I do something like `code` Assuming[q != q1, Simplify[b]]`code`.

Comment: @Paco, use backticks for `code`!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So your goal is to have a function similar to the delta function in that it can deal with purely symbolic variables instead of having attribute `NumericFunction` as does `KroneckerDelta`.

Here is a solution that doesn't require holding the expressions during the evaluation. What I do instead is to define `MyDiscreteDelta` only for situations where it occurs in an explicit sum, i.e., an expression whose `Head` has been converted from `Sum` to `Plus`. At that stage, you'll know that the dummy variable of `Sum` has been replaced by the actual values, which in your case includes symbolic names drawn from the set `qpV`, not just numbers.

I changed the definition slightly so that `MyDiscreteDelta` takes only one argument instead of two, more like the `DiracDelta` function. That way you can also insert more complicated expression as a condition in `MyDiscreteDelta`, such as `MyDiscreteDelta[q^2 - qp^2]` etc. This is also what your initial $\LaTeX$ example looked like.

To make the definitions active in the desired situations, I use `TagSetDelayed`. This can only be done using another auxiliary function that represents the multiplications in which `MyDiscreteDelta` might occur - which is a level below the summation:

```
ClearAll[MyDiscreteDelta, DiscreteDeltaTimes]

MyDiscreteDelta /: Times[any_, MyDiscreteDelta[expr_]] := 
 DiscreteDeltaTimes[any, expr]

MyDiscreteDelta /: Plus[any_, MyDiscreteDelta[expr_]] := 
 If[expr === 0, any + 1, any]

DiscreteDeltaTimes /: Plus[DiscreteDeltaTimes[any_, expr_], other_] :=
  If[expr === 0, any, 0] + other

DiscreteDeltaTimes /: 
 MakeBoxes[DiscreteDeltaTimes[x_, y_], StandardForm] := 
 RowBox[{ToBoxes[x], "\[ThinSpace]", "MyDiscreteDelta", "[", 
   ToBoxes[y], "]"}]

Clear[qV, qpV, f, g]

a = Sum[f[q] Sum[g[qp] MyDiscreteDelta[q - qp], {qp, qpV}], {q, qV}]
```

> $\displaystyle\sum _q^{\text{qV}}$ `f[q]` $\displaystyle\sum
>    _{\text{qp}}^{\text{qpV}}$ `g[qp] MyDiscreteDelta[q-qp]`

```
a/.{qpV->{q,q1,q2,q3,q4}}
```

> $\displaystyle\sum _q^{\text{qV}}$ `f[q] g[q]`

In the first output, the `MakeBoxes` definition above gets applied so that the auxiliary function `DiscreteDeltaTimes` is hidden from view.