# Follow-up to "How to differentiate formally?": Efficiency concern

Tags: performance-tuning, variable-definitions, summation, attributes

In link to "[how to differentiate formally?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16375/how-to-differentiate-formally)" and particularly to the answer by @Jens,
I want to do something like this:

```
Clear[sum,x,A,n1,n2,result];
sum = Sum[x[i,j] A[j], {i,1,n1},{j,1,n2}];
result = D[sum,x[a,b], NonConstants -> {x}];
x /: D[x[i_,j_], x[k_,l_], NonConstants -> {x}] := 
  KroneckerDelta[i,k]*KroneckerDelta[j,l];
Timing[result]
```

(that is to say differentiate with `NonConstants` and then evaluate while applying the `KroneckerDelta` rule, which is what takes times).

This takes a long time (~6sec in this minimal example, a prohibitive time in the case of my actual application), but when re-executing the cell (or another cell with copy-pasted content), it is much faster (~0sec in this example).

I believe this is because during the first run Mathematica tries out different un-optimized ways to do what it is asked to do, and at second run it uses the optimal way for the given types and variables.

**My question is:** how can I input informations ressembling those Mathematica found out during the first run to directly do the fast calculation ?

**EDIT**: An element of an answer can come from "[Simplification of double symbolic sums containing a DiscreteDelta without explicit summation range](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18235/34931)", adapted to :

```
Clear[sum,x,A,n1,n2,result];
sum = Sum[x[i,j] A[j], {i,n1}, {j,n2}] ;
result = D[sum, x[a, b], NonConstants -> {x}];
x /: D[x[i_,j_], x[k_,l_], NonConstants -> {x}] := HIS[i,k,j,l];
Timing[result]
```

which is very fast. (Note the summation is in the form `{i,n1}`, and, in the link above, the `HoldForm`/`ReleaseHold` succession to evaluate the `HIS` function.)

This does not answer the question, but offers a nice workaround.