# simplifying indefinite sums containing Kronecker Deltas

Tags: function-construction, simplifying-expressions, summation, algebra

I want to simplify indefinite sums containing KroneckerDeltas, e.g:

$\sum_{k,k1,q} \beta(q) \beta(k+k1+q) \delta(k1+q)= \sum_{k,q} \beta(k)\beta(q)$  where $k,k1,q \;\epsilon \; \mathrm{R}$

```
Sum[ β[q] β[k + q + k1] KroneckerDelta[k1 + q], k, k1,q]
```

however

```
Sum[ β[q] β[k + q + k1] KroneckerDelta[k1 + q], k, k1, q] // FullSimplify
```

doesn't work, i.e I don't get

```
Sum[β[q] β[k ], k, q]
```

I also tried

```
c = FullSimplify[KroneckerDelta[q + k1] β[q] β[k + q + k1]]
Assuming[c != 0, FullSimplify[Sum[c, k, k1, q]]]
```

but it just returns the input sum.

I have found [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18235/simplification-of-double-symbolic-sums-containing-a-discretedelta-without-explic?rq=1) a custom `MyDiscreteDelta` function which also doesn't work.
Is there a way to achieve such simplifications?

Comment: There is no way to achieve this because the result you are after is in general not correct: in order to get it you need to rewrite and reorder the summations, which is only possible under special convergence conditions. You can simplify expressions using a custom `KroneckerDelta` and `TagSetDelayed`, e.g. `\[Delta] /: f_[x_ + y_] \[Delta][x_ + z_] := f[y - z]`, but you'll need to keep track of summation indices and make sure your operations are actually mathematically correct...

Comment: @FidelI.Schaposnik thanks for the reply. Your custom ` \[Delta]` is a good idea but it does not take away the sum over `k1` in ` Sum[β[q] β[k + q + k1] δ[k1 + q], k, k1, q]`. I can only manually erase it?

Comment: Can you also please post your comment as an answer. I think it's helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Posting as an answer at the request of the OP**

*There is probably no built-in way to achieve what you want because the result you are after is in general not correct: in order to get it you need to rewrite and reorder the summations, which is only possible under special convergence conditions.*

That being said, if you are sure beforehand that all your manipulations will be legal you can automatically simplify expressions like the ones you present using custom symbols and `TagSetDelayed`. For example

```
MyDelta /: f_[x_ + y_] MyDelta[x_ + z_] := f[y - z]
```

will make an expression like `f[q]f[k+k1+q]MyDelta[k1+q]` transform to `f[q]f[k]`, and something like

```
MySum /: MySum[expr_ KroneckerDelta[x_ + y_], left___, x_, right___] := MySum[expr /. x -> -y, left, right]
```

will take expressions like `MySum[f[i + j] KroneckerDelta[j + k], i, j, k]` into `MySum[f[i - k], i, k]`.

Depending on your intended application, you may want to add stuff (e.g. make `MySum` linear, regularize `MyDelta[0]` under the summation sign, etc.), or make some of these replacements manually instead of automatically... but you should always keep in mind that this symbolic transformations can go wildly wrong if you are not very careful about how you implement things, and to which problems you apply them...